# Default.aspx in a virtual directory raises a CS1061 error

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7.5

I'm staging an ASP Web Forms application for system testing.  We have two URLs that will use the same code, changing their content based on the URL.  So I configured two virtual directories in IIS to map to one physical path.  Say the virtual directories are `TTP/Site1` and `TTP/Site2`, and they both map to `TTP/SiteCommon`.

However, the `Default.aspx` page raises a CS1061 compilation error:

> CS1061: 'ASP.ttp_site1_default_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'btn_login_Click' and no extension method 'btn_login_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.ttp_site1_default_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The error is on this line:

```
<asp:Button ID="btn_login" runat="server" Text="Log in" OnClick="btn_login_Click" />
```

I get the same message for TTP/Site2, and on the same line.

I looked up prior Stack Overflow questions, and confirmed that `btn_login_Click` in Default is **protected** not **private**.

Any ideas?

ETA per request:

```
    protected void btn_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/login.aspx");

    }
```

ETA2:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/main.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="RIF.Default1" %>
```

Comment: Can you post the Page direction from the top of your ASPX files, as well as the filename of the code behind? It seems to me that those aren't hooking up.

Comment: Posted.  Hmm -- maybe the ~/ is what's throwing things off?

Comment: Oh duh.  I forgot to upload `web.config`.  FAIL.

Comment: ... and uploading that results in HTTP error 500, internal error.  Checking the site from a browser on the server results in 404.

Comment: So double check the configuration in IIS to make sure it's configured with .NET 4.0 and has an app pool etc?

Comment: The App Pool list confirms that it's configured for .NET 4.0.  (I fixed *that* yesterday.)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your class is named Default1 and it's in the RIF namespace.

Also, if you're using Web Site instead of Web Application Project, change CodeBehind to CodeFile. [See MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydy4x04a%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/main.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="RIF.Default1" %>
```

Comment: The class signature is `public partial class Default1 : System.Web.UI.Page` and the namespace is correct.  The other files also use `CodeBehind` so I believe this project is a web app project.

Comment: Is Default.aspx.cs in the same folder with Default.aspx?

Comment: Yes it is.  All the `aspx` and `aspx.cs` files are in `~/TTP/SiteCommon`.